# Save event on Magento custom admin extension

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

```
is there any event in admin
```

for when save item or save and continue button pressed in my custom extension?

[image]

Comment: please check this link [link](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add that event yourself to your controller, to check what button is clicked you can do the following:

In your block widget definition for your edit form you need to configure your save and continue url for the button:

```
public function getSaveAndContinueUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array(
        '_current'   => true,
        'back'       => 'edit',
    ));
}
```

And in the saveAction function you can then check if the parameter back is used:

```
    $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);

    if ($redirectBack) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
            'id'    => $productId,
            '_current'=>true
        ));
    }
    Mage::dispatchevent('myevent',array('mydata'=>$data,'rediredit'=>$redirectBack));
```

You also need to set

In the event observer you can check the clicked button, when rediredit is false the save button is clicked, else the save and continue edit button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Besides creating the event in the controller, you can also use the native events defined in the model class `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. To do this, you simply need to define  `$_eventPrefix` in your custom model class:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Course extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'course'; 
    protected $_eventObject = 'course'; //optional, default is 'object'

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('module/course');
    }
}
```

With that, you can listen to all the standard events associated with `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, for example:

- course_save_before
- course_load_before
- course_delete_after
- course_save_commit_after
- and many more

Answer (score 1):

You can refer magento Link for the Admin Event

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events

Hear you got all magento admin event list.